# ImageVIew in wrong position

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, location, positioning

When I place an `ImageView` in the screen on the design tab of the `activity_main.xml` and run the program, the `ImageView` alway go to the top left corner of the screen instead of the location I placed it in.
And if I try to place it with code like follows:

```
    LinearLayout meulayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    meulayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


ImageView meuview = new ImageView(this);
meuview.setImageResource(R.drawable.vermelho);
meuview.setX(1000f);
meuview.setY(1000f);

meulayout.addView(meuview);
```

It simply doesn't appear on the screen at all.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it, is make layout file with code like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.vestasoft.vadim.xxx.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And You can to add the other tags in ImageView component, to locate it like you want. It's bad way to hard locate component like you do, using location by pixels.

Comment: I also think your way is better but what make me more confused is that the way i showed in my code used to work one weak ago and out of the sudden stoped working.

Comment: Maybe you added some changes in your code. And my advice for you. Every time, when you start your code, do 'build -> clean project', it will help you get rid of any problems.